# Запуск Chrome с флагом геолокации

Tags: google-chrome, cmd

Нужно запустить Chrome через cmd с флагом геолокации (чтобы Chrome её не блокировал), напомните пож-та название флага.

Либо можно запускать с отключением вообще всех блокировок, но этот флаг я тоже забыл и найти не смог